Nuxt replace startup/restart page
I want to replace this screen with a custom HTML file:

Why?
I use Nuxt with Tauri and want some part of the loading screen to have "data-tauri-drag-region" so I can drag it even in the loading state.
I have already tried to change the "spaLoadingTemplate" or "devServer" > "loadingTemplate" but this didn't work.
